# CSS rules from component are ignored when using slots

Tags: astrojs

What I expect to happen is the `h3` within the `<Card>` component to be styled.

I have created the styles for the `h3` element within the `<Card>` component. The `.card` styles are applied but not the `.card h3` styles are not.

I've searched the docs thinking this might be a scoping issue but couldn't find anything. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**Features.astro**

```
<ul>
    {features.map(feature =>
        <li>
            <Card>
                <h3>{feature.title}</h3>
                <p>{feature.body}</p>    
            </Card>
        </li>
    )}
</ul>
```

**Card.astro**

```
<div class="card">
    <slot />
</div>

<style>
    .card {
        background: red;
    }

    .card h3 {
        background: black;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: .5rem;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`<style>` tags are scoped by default](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#scoped-styles), this means they only apply styles to elements directly inside the file. Because your `<h3>` element is actually in the `Features.astro` file it is outside the scope of `Card.astro`. If you want to style `<h3>` from inside `Card.astro` you would have to use the [global styling](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#global-styles)